# Calling Unmanaged Code from Managed Code

Tags: c#, ipc

Anyone know how i fix this error?

ERROR:

> A call to PInvoke function has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

I am using P/Invoke to call a native code from a managed code. Native code is being imported via dynamic link libraries.

Steps are

1. Locating .dll containing these function.
2. Loading .dll into memory
3. Locating the address of function in memory
4. Transforming this memory representation of object to a data format (marshalling)

DLL has a function with declaration

```
long    __stdcall Connect (long,long,long,long,long,long,long,long);`
```

In my application i created a delegate

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private delegate long delConnect(long a, long b, long c, long d, long e, long f, long g, long h);`
```

Then i created a class for loading dll and locating address of function in memory

`static class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);


    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);
}`
```

Now when i am trying to use the function then i am getting error

```
IntPtr pDll = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary("serial.dll");
IntPtr pAddressOfFunctionToCall = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(pDll, "_Connect@32");
delConnect connect = (delConnect)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pAddressOfFunctionToCall,typeof(delConnect)); 
long check = connect(1, 0, 12, 9600, 0, 0, 8, 0);
bool result = NativeMethods.FreeLibrary(pDll);`
```

I have used "_Connect@32" instead of "Connect" in function name parameters of GetProcAddress method, because of name mangling.

When i am debugging i get this error at line containing statement

> long check = connect(1, 0, 12, 9600, 0, 0, 8, 0);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C/C++ `long` is 32 bit in Windows, so an `int` in `.net`. Try changing it (on Unix it's more like an `IntPtr`)

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)] 
private delegate int delConnect(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, int g, int h);
```

And perhaps instead of `StdCall` try `Cdecl`:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

For the `DllImport` of Windows API you should use

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
```

So that if possible .NET uses the Unicode variant, and not the Ansi variant.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're using `LoadLibrary()` rather than just PInvoking directly?

What happens if you try this instead:

```
[DllImport("serial.dll", EntryPoint = "_Connect@32", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
static extern int DelConnect(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, int g, int h);
```

(Note C# int == C++ long, normally)